# Understanding a proof in Milne's 'Field and Galois Theory'

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

Let $G = \{ \sigma_1, \dots , \sigma_m \} \ (\sigma_1 = e) $ be a finite group of automorphisms of a field $E$, and let $F$ be the fixed field of $G$. Then $[E:F] \leq (G:1)$.

I will omit most of the proof, which I understand. It's just the conclusion that excapes me and I'm sure its something sill that I'm missing.
We choose $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_n \in E$, where $n>m$....

After a while we conclude that there are non-trivial $c_1, \dots, c_n \in F$ such that $\alpha_1 c_1 + \dots + \alpha_n c_n = 0$. It's not stated, but this implies that $[E:F] \leq n$, yes? But how does this imply that $[E:F] < m$? I feel like I'm taking crazy pills!

For reference the full proof is Theorem 3.4 on page 36.
http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows that *for any* $n > m$ and any $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in E$, the $\alpha_i$ are linearly dependent over $F$. Hence, for a set $\{\alpha_i\mid i = 1,\dots, j\}\subseteq E$ to be linearly independent over $F$ (in particular, if we want the set $\{\alpha_i\}$ to have a chance to be a basis for $E/F$), we must have $j\leq m$, so that $[E : F]\leq m$.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The point of this is to show that $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is always $F$-linearly independent for any $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\in E^n$ for any $n>m$, I think you agree with me when I say that this is what has been proven.

The implicit conclusion (to show that $n:=[E:F]\leq m$) is to take a base $(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)$ of $E$ over $F$. If $n>m$ then $(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)$ cannot be linearly independent by what has already been done so it is not a base, whence $n\leq m$.